# Redirecting to new route value after calling action has changed name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jeditable

Apologies for the confusing title...

I have a URL, something like:

admin/lists/list-name

list-name can be changed by the user.

I use [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to allow in-place editing.

There's a method in one of my controllers that looks a little something like the below.

My question is, once the "list" has been renamed, obviously the url is no longer correct, it should be /admin/lists/

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeWishlistName(string id, string value)
{
  _service.Renamelist(Convert.ToInt32(id), value);

  //what should go here??
}
```

What should I do in order to effectively redirect to the new url?

Comment: is ChangeWishListName called from jeditable? an ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

is the ChangeWishListName action called from jeditable as an ajax call? If so the server side action can't do the redirect.

You could do the redirect on the client side with javascript. You can redirect the page using window.location in the success callback function.

```
window.location = "/admin/lists/newname";
```